# Adding text from textbox to Html.ActionLink

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have method that add roles for user. It works fine when it it constants string. Now i want to give role name from input and here i have problem with passing text to actionlink. How to do that ?  Here is the code that i have working with constants string:

View:

```
@model AdminMVC.Models.Admin.UserViewModel
<input class="form-control" type="text" name="role" placeholder="Role name">
@Html.ActionLink("Add role", "AddRoleToUser", new { id = Model.ApplicationUser.Id }, new { @class = "fas fa-user-edit" })
```

Controller:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> AddRoleToUser(string id, string role)
        {
            var user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(id);

            if (await _roleManager.RoleExistsAsync("NewRole"))
            {
                await _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, "NewRole");
            }

            return RedirectToAction("Roles");
        }
```

Comment: you have to use route values for your action link to send values to the controller. but then again you will have to get the input value and set it as the action link's route value. you can use a form to do that (replace the action link and use a submit button instead). or you could use jQuery to dynamically set the action link's route value before performing the request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a form to post the value:

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("AddRoleToUser", new { id = Model.ApplicationUser.Id }))
{
  <input class="form-control" type="text" name="role" placeholder="Role name">
  <input type="submit" value="Add role" class="fas fa-user-edit" />
}
```